# How to create dynamic checkbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an application where I require to add dynamic checkbox list. Please anyone tell me how to add dynamic checkbox list using C#.

Comment: what have you tried and where are you stuck?
WinForms application, WPF or ASP.NET ?

Comment: When you mean dynamic, do you mean in code, or programically?

Comment: @Matten, I think it's ASP.NET as thats what the heading says.

Comment: Possible duplicate post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626889/dynamically-programatically-adding-check-boxes-and-checkedchanged-events

Comment: @Jethro -- I should improve my reading skills :)

Comment: @Matten, don't worry been there a many times myself. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Put a placeHolder on your form with the ID `placeHolder` and add the following code to your `Page_Load()`:

```
CheckBoxList cbList = new CheckBoxList();
    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cbList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Checkbox " + i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

placeHolder.Controls.Add(cbList);
```

This will add 10 CheckBox objects within your `CheckBoxList(cbList)`.

Use the following code to examine each `CheckBox` object within the `CheckBoxList`

```
foreach(ListItem li in cbList.Items)
{
    var value = li.Value;
    var text = li.Text;
    bool isChecked = li.Selected;
}
```

The placeholder is used to add the `CheckBoxList` to the form at runtime, using a placeholder will give you more control over the web page where the `CheckBoxList` and its items will appear.

Answer (score 2):

At code behind you can create new ASP.NET Controls and you can add these controls to your page. All you need to do is to create new [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) Object and add [ListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.windows.documents.listitem.aspx) to it. Finally, you need to add your CheckBoxList to your [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx).

```
// Create CheckBoxList
CheckBoxList list= new CheckBoxList();

// Set attributes for CheckBoxList
list.ID = "CheckBoxList1";
list.AutoPostBack = true;

// Create ListItem
ListItem listItem = new ListItem();

// Set attributes for ListItem
listItem .ID = "ListItem1";

// Add ListItem to CheckBoxList
list.Items.Add(listItem );

// Add your new control to page
this.Form.Controls.Add(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
    CheckBoxList chkList = new CheckBoxList();
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chkList.ID = "ChkUser";
    chkList.AutoPostBack = true;
    chkList.RepeatColumns = 6;
    chkList.DataSource = us.GetUserDS();
    chkList.DataTextField = "User_Name";
    chkList.DataValueField = "User_Id";                        
    chkList.DataBind();

    Panel pUser = new Panel();

    if (pUserGrp != "")   
    {
        pUser.GroupingText = pUserGrp ;
        chk.Text = pUserGrp;            
    }
    else 
    {
        pUser.GroupingText = "Non Assigned Group";
        chk.Text = "Non Assigned group";
    }
    pUser.Controls.Add(chk);
    pUser.Controls.Add(chkList);
    this.Form.Controls.Add(pUser);
```