# Do I need to differentiate dynamically created Checkboxes from each other?

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkbox, event-handling, windows-store-apps

I've got this code to dynamically create checkboxes and hook them up to a shared OnTapped event handler:

```
private void CreateNewGroup(int currentItem, string groupName)
{
    CheckBox ckbx = new CheckBox();
    ckbx.Content = groupName;
    ckbx.Tag = currentItem; // Don't know if this is needed
    ckbx.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(this.Checkbox_OnTapped);
    stackPanelCheckBoxesParent.Children.Add(ckbx);
}
```

...as the comment shows, I don't know if assigning a val to the Tag property is superfluous. The only reason I added it is because here: [Dynamically (programatically) adding check boxes and checkedchanged events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626889/dynamically-programatically-adding-check-boxes-and-checkedchanged-events), a couple of people say to be sure to assing to the ID property of the dynamically created checkbox. Yet in Windows 8 C# apps there is no such property, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx):

> A common use for the Tag property is to store data that is closely
>   associated with the control. For example, if you have a control that
>   displays information about a customer, you might store a DataSet that
>   contains the customer's order history in that control's Tag property
>   so the data can be accessed quickly.

So unless you need to associate an object with your control you can omit it, will you be later accessing the `currentItem`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no technical requirement in Windows Store apps to differentiate between controls based on their properties. Whether you need to associate `currentItem` to your checkboxes depends on what your event handler does. If you need to do something with the `currentItem` related to it, you will need a way to access it from the event handler. Setting it as `Tag` on the control makes that pretty easy:

```
public delegate void TappedEventHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (int)((CheckBox)sender).Tag;
    // do something with the value
}
```

I'm not a big fan of dinamically creating controls this way, though. Most of the time the same result is easier to achieve by using data binding. In your case you'd need the following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As `DataContext` of your page you'd need the following in the view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    private bool _isChecked;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                // react to value change if necessary   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CheckBox` state will now automatically reflect in the corresponding `Group` instance. You can call additional code in `IsChecked` setter if necessary.