# Get real time input from programmatically generated elements in C# form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, input, real-time

How to get value of checkboxes (and the textbox upon change in text) in real time with form particulars that are all generated via code?

This following code produces a form upon button press, the form has checkboxes and a richtextbox. Ideally I want any interaction to have an effect, so if I paste in a grid of ones and zeros the checkboxes update, and once a checkbox gets click, the corresponding one or zero in the textarea will update (So that I can then copy the grid (matrix) out and into another program.

I know how to get the events using the visual studio GUI maker, but not from a programmatically created form like this.

```
    private void begin_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Build the child form
        Form check_box = new Form();
        check_box.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        // Get the values from the textboxes
        int height = Convert.ToInt16(this.height_input.Text);
        int width = Convert.ToInt16(this.width_input.Text);

        // Set the dimensions of the form
        check_box.Width = width * 15 + 40;
        check_box.Height = ( height * 15 + 40 ) * 3;

        // Build checkboxes for the checkbox form
        CheckBox[] chk;
        chk = new CheckBox[height * width];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
            {
                chk[count] = new CheckBox();
                chk[count].Name = count.ToString();
                chk[count].Width = 15; // because the default is 100px for text
                chk[count].Height = 15;
                chk[count].Location = new Point(j * 15, i * 15);
                chk[count].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
                check_box.Controls.Add(chk[count]);
                count += 1;
                //Console.WriteLine(" i: " + i + " j: " + j + " Count: " + count);
            }
        }

        RichTextBox output_area;
        output_area = new RichTextBox();
        output_area.Location = new Point(chk[0].Location.X, chk[count-1].Location.Y + 30);
        check_box.Controls.Add(output_area);
        output_area.Text = "hello world\n1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\n0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1\nthese ones and zeros are meant to update in real time!";
        output_area.Width = check_box.Width - 40;
        output_area.Height = check_box.Height / 2;

        // Run the form
        check_box.ShowDialog();
    }
```

EDIT:

I have added the event handler and it's working, however I can't access the checkbox form, only the main form.

```
    private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        CheckBox x = (CheckBox)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Name.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically (programatically) adding check boxes and checkedchanged events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626889/dynamically-programatically-adding-check-boxes-and-checkedchanged-events) + tons of other results from google...

Comment: @BartoszKP, that link suggests that I have a loop that checks each checkbox continuously? I'm not even sure where I would put it, the code seems to pause at the `check_box.ShowDialog();` line.

Comment: No it doesn't. It shows you how to programmatically assign an event to a generated `CheckBox`.

Comment: Ok, so I have the event handler working, however I can't access the generated form, I can't access `check_box` at all.

Comment: Please don't modify your post as you go along. This is not a helpdesk service, and more importantly - this is not about *you*. SO is a place to collect general questions&answers useful to everyone, not for detailed hand guiding for beginners. Please use the vast amount of information available on the internet - in this case .NET tutorials and MSDN documentation. Starting tip for you: read about properties your objects expose for you: [`CheckBox.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @BartoszKP, No worries. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code updates matrix text in the rich text box when check box check state changed.

```
    RichTextBox output_area;
    CheckBox[] chk;
    Size MatrixSize;
    private void begin_button_Click()
    {
        // Build the child form
        Form check_box = new Form();
        check_box.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        check_box.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        // Get the values from the textboxes
        int height = Convert.ToInt16("10");
        int width = Convert.ToInt16("7");

        MatrixSize = new Size(width, height);

        // Set the dimensions of the form
        check_box.Width = width * 15 + 40;
        check_box.Height = (height * 15 + 40) * 3;

        // Build checkboxes for the checkbox form

        chk = new CheckBox[height * width];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
            {
                chk[count] = new CheckBox();
                chk[count].Name = count.ToString();
                chk[count].Width = 15; // because the default is 100px for text
                chk[count].Height = 15;
                chk[count].Location = new Point(j * 15, i * 15);
                check_box.Controls.Add(chk[count]);
                chk[count].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox1_CheckedChanged);


                count += 1;
                //Console.WriteLine(" i: " + i + " j: " + j + " Count: " + count);
            }
        }


        output_area = new RichTextBox();
        output_area.Location = new Point(chk[0].Location.X, chk[count - 1].Location.Y + 30);
        check_box.Controls.Add(output_area);
        output_area.Text = "hello world\n1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\n0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1\nthese ones and zeros are meant to update in real time!";
        output_area.Width = check_box.Width - 40;
        output_area.Height = check_box.Height / 2;

        // Run the form
        check_box.ShowDialog();
    }


    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
        Debug.WriteLine(c.Name);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= MatrixSize.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= MatrixSize.Width; j++)
            {
                if (chk[count].Checked)
                {
                    sb.Append("1,");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append("0,");
                }
                count += 1;
            }
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }

        output_area.Text = sb.ToString(); 

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Inside the event handler I added `char token = ' ';` and then `sb[sb.Length-1] = token;` at the end of the inner for loop so that I could delimit the end of each line (It's a matrix I'm using in matlab). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the .Designer file that the form designer generates for you!

Anyway, in your loop, try something like this:

```
chk[count].CheckedChanged += MyFancyHandler;
```

And the handler itself will look just like a normal handler:

```
private void MyFancyHandler( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    // ...
}
```

Also notice that the `sender` argument there will contain a reference to whichever checkbox/control the event refers to.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have a `.Designer` file for the checkbox form, because the entire thing is generated during runtime. I have no idea how to access the handler's for the checkboxes.

Comment: Maybe what I should have written was "create some form, add a few checkboxes and hook up some events", and then have a look at the designer file! Just to see how it does it!

Comment: Ah I see, see how it works normally so that I can replicate it for my situation?